# Excel Formula caculating number days of year between 2 dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for an excel formula to calculating the number of days from years between "Start date" & "end date"

Example :
My start date is 06/19/2020
My end date is 06/20/2023

I would to know on this example the number of days from year 2020 => from start date ; year 2021 (full year) ; year 2022 (full year) ; 2023 => from end date

Result :
number of days of 2020 : 195
number of days of 2021 : 365
number of days of 2022 : 365
number of days of 2023 : 170

in my databse i have different start date and end date by line to x year

Thanks for your help

Comment: just calculate `endDate - startDate`, you may have to remove the date formatting from the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply substract one cell value from another, if for example:

A1 = TODAY() (which returns today's date)
A2 = 1/01/2019

B1 = A1-A2 = 765 days

Hope it was helpful for you[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the **DATEDIF** function:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73268311/13406526

Sorry, but I'm a newbie, cannot add comments.