# Identify Gap Years Between Multiple Dates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

For example, I have these list of dates (These are of type 'date')

```
Sept 1, 2010
July 1, 2016
July 1, 2022
```

The gap years between these dates are 6 years. Another Example:

```
Sept 1, 2010
July 1, 2012
Sept 1, 2014
July 1, 2016
```

The gap years between these dates is 2. How will I make a formula to identify the gap years?

Comment: Are these true dates? Or Text that looks like a date?

Comment: These are of type 'date'

Comment: *The gap years between these dates is 2* Your last date is 2026, so the gap would be 12. I guess it's a typo but just to make sure...

Comment: Yes, its a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column:

```
    Gap_row = Previous Row - Current Row
    D2 = IFERROR(IF(D1<0;0;C2-C1);0)
```

[image]

Then create a pivot table for year and show Max(Gap_Row).
The Grand total for Max of Year Gap is the Year Gap for those rows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check out **DATEDIF** function:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Starting at your **second** date, just do `=YEAR(A2)-YEAR(A1)`